# Rigorous construction of partition induced by minimal covering transformation

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems

This is closely related to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224834/definition-of-a-locally-lifted-measure/3225674#3225674) I recently asked. This was about the definition of a locally lifted measure described by Keane in his seminal paper on $g$-measures [1]. I received a good answer, but another way of constructing a measure is through the construction of a particular partition, which I mention in the other post. For convenience I repeat the essentials:

The setting is as follows: Let $(X,T)$ be a dynamical system, where $X$ is a compact metric space $(X,d)$, and $T$ is a minimal covering transformation. By this we (read Keane) mean that:

1. $T$ is everywhere $n$-to-1 ($n\geq 2$).
2. $T$ is a local homeomorphism.
3. There exists a $C>1$, such that for all $x\in X$ there exists a $\delta_x>0$, such that $d(x,y)<\delta_x\implies d(Tx,Ty)\geq Cd(x,y)$.
4. For all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $N\in\mathbb N$, such that $T^{-N}(x)$ is $\varepsilon$ dense in $X$, for all $x$.

A typical example of covering transformations are the expanding circle endomorphisms, $T_n:S^1\to S^1$, given by $T_ne^{i\theta}=e^{in\theta}$. For these examples we can partition $S^1$ into the disjoint sets $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$, where each $X_i=\left[\frac{2\pi(i-1)}{n},\frac{2\pi i}{n}\right)$. These partitions are important, because for each $i$ the restricted map $T|_{X_i}:X_i\to S^1$ is a homeomorphism. This motivates my question:

> For the general case, with $X$ an arbitrary compact metric space and $T$ an arbitrary covering transformation satisfying points 1) through 4) above, does a covering transformation always induce a disjoint partition $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of $X$ such that each restricted map $T|_{X_i}$ is a homeomorphism? Importantly I require the number of sets in the partition, $n$, to equal the number of covers of the covering transformation.

My instinct is yes, but I am not sure how to rigorously construct such a partition. My idea would be to use choice somehow to order the $n$ elements of each $T^{-1}x$ such that we can take $X_i=\bigcup_{x\in X} x_i$, where $x_i$ is the $i$-th element in $T^{-1}x$ according our ordering. I am not sure how to rigorously construct such an ordering though, and would appreciate any input.

[1] *Keane, Michael*, [**Strongly mixing g-measures**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01425715), Invent. Math. 16, 309-324 (1972). [ZBL0241.28014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0241.28014).

Comment: Is $T$ just a continuous map $X \to X$ with properties 1. - 4.? Can you give an example? Are there any requirements concerning the $X_i$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes indeed. Please see my edit for an example. The only requirements for the $X_i$ are that they are disjoint, their union is all of $X$, and $T$ restricted to each of them is a homeomorphism onto $X$.

Comment: Do you really need that $T(X_i) = X$?

Comment: @PaulFrost That would be ideal, yes, but if you can think of another partition that doesn't satisfy that I might still be able to use it

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $X$ is compact (not necessarily metric) and $T : X \to X$ is a local homeomorphism. Then each $x \in X$ has an open neighborhood $U_x$ which is mapped by $T$ homeomorphically onto $T(U_x)$. By compactness there exist $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that the $U_i = U_{x_i}$ cover $X$. Now define
$$X_i = U_i \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^{i-1}U_j \subset U_i .$$

Comment: Thanks. I should have specifically pointed out though that I require the number of sets in the partition to equal the $n$ defining the covering transformation, and this proof does not guarantee that if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I see! Indeed it is said in your question, but perhaps you should explicitly add this to the above text.